# Install packages without internet Red Hat

Tags: linux, package, redhat, rhel, hyperledger

I need to install [Hyperledger](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric) on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux server that won't be connected to the internet. What I'll need to install is likely the Go language and Docker however given I have no internet connection I can't just use a package manager.

I've [read about methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline) to do this with Ubuntu that mention copying .deb files over or otherwise using tools - would this work with RHEL and if not would anyone be able to recommend a way of doing this? (or any advice for achieveing this generally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the package "downloadonly" on a RHEL Server with internet connection:

```
# yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly
```

Then download the packages you want:

```
# yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=<directory> <package>
```

Transfer and install them on a Server without internet connection:

```
# rpm -ivh package.rpm
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, at least with nginx. Yum downloaded several rpms but when I `rpm -ivh nginx-1.12` it complains about missing dependencies (which are there as .rpms) and dependencies of dependencies which are not even in the downloaddir

Comment: @Marged you need to run localinstall, rpm -ivh does not install missing dependency packages, try # yum localinstall package.rpm